# How can you select the text in a div (for copying into the clipboard) from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div containing some text that I would like the user to be able to easily copy from the page (via the clipboard).  Is there a cross browser way to select all of the text within a div on a mouseclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these both:
http://yangshuai.googlepages.com/jquerycopyplugin
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard

Answer (score 2):

Cross browser support for clipboard copying via Javascript requires using Flash to get around Firefox/Netscape's security, which denies access to the clipboard. If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) you can easily make use of the [clipboard](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard) plugin. If you are rolling your own Javascript without using jQuery then this [blog post](http://www.jeffothy.com/weblog/clipboard-copy/) may help.

In addition, you can actually adjust Firefox's security permissions to allow scripts access to your clipboard. A good [walkthrough](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-2-dijit/advanced-editing-and-display/editor-rich-text/setup-clipboard-action) is available at dojotoolkit.org. This usually isn't the path pursued as it would require each of your users to make this adjustment. Much easier to use Flash as it works with all modern browsers (Safari, IE, Firefox, and Opera).

Answer (score 1):

```
<SPAN ID="copytext" STYLE="height:150;width:162;background-color:pink">
This text will be copied onto the clipboard when you click the button below. Try it!
</SPAN>
<TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" STYLE="display:none;">
</TEXTAREA>
<BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard();">Copy to Clipboard</BUTTON>    

function ClipBoard() 
    {
    holdtext.innerText = copytext.innerText;
    Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
    Copied.execCommand("Copy");
    }
```

[From Here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3458851)

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/replace-text-inside-a-div-element) may have some clues for you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to select text in a div, and didn't really want to use the flash approach to just copy it (though that is a nice tool to have available).

I ended up just doing this:

```
function selectIncidentIDText (incidentIDTxtEl) {
    incidentIDTxtEl.select();
}
<h:inputText value="(IncidentID: #{ViewIncidentBean.incident.id})" readonly="true" onclick="selectIncidentIDText(this);"/>
```

That works well enough for what I wanted, albeit it is a bit ugly.