# Using prototype instead of innerHTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

How to use prototype instead of innerHTML while assigning the values to the elements of the html page??

Comment: `prototype` and `innerHTML` server completely different purposes in JavaScript. Read some tutorials on those topics.

Comment: This is not an answerable question right now. Please provide more information and perhaps some source code of what you have tried.

Comment: people suggest to use prototype instead of innerHTML... I'm very new to html, so please suggest..
Can we replace prototype with innerHTML

Comment: `$('fruits').update('<p>Kiwi, banana <em>and</em> apple.</p>');` from http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/update

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace text inside a DIV element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/replace-text-inside-a-div-element)

Comment: I think ".update" method is the in-built method for jQuery.. but I'm using javascript. Is there any in-built method in js?

Comment: You need to clarify `people suggest to use prototype instead of innerHTML`. Where did you read this? Show the link. As it is, I can only guess the "people" mean using prototype.js library..

Comment: Is there any method in prototype.js library to update the text of an element?

Comment: @Pooja yes, I just linked a duplicate question of that

Comment: @ Esailija:  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/replace-text-inside-a-div-element"... this is the link where they say its not a good style to use innerHTML...

Comment: You didn't know that link before you made your question and comment about "people suggesting prototype" so I think you're trolling

Comment: @ Esailija: whoever has posted it in that link come under "people" category.. u asked me for the link and I posted it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHTML` and   `prototype` are used for two completely different purposes in JavaScript. there is no comparison.

see the following links

**[InnerHTML](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CFwQFjAD&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=bo_pT_eQMcXyrQes1LybDg&usg=AFQjCNELATOoGZR0N736YIaYN2ozWMTIUg)**

**[Prototype](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)**

Comment: I think the OP means [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/). Or maybe not…