# Replace text inside a div element

Tags: javascript, html

What should i do if i need to replace the "test test" message with custom one using JavaScript?

```
<div class="outputmsg_container" style="" id="output_messages"><
    button class="btn btn-icon close icon-cross" onclick="GlideUI.get().clearOutputMessages(this); return false;">
        <span class="sr-only">Close Messages"</span>
            </button>
            <div class="outputmsg_div">
                <div class="outputmsg outputmsg_error notification notification-error"><img class="outputmsg_image" src="images/outputmsg_error_24.gifx" alt="">
                <span class="outputmsg_text">test test</span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Use `.replace('string to replace', 'new string')`.

Comment: `.innerHTML('new text')`

Comment: i have updated the question, can you review now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace text inside a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/how-do-i-replace-text-inside-a-div-element)

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` to change the `HTML` inside an element.

```html
<label for="newhtml">HTML (or text) to be inserted inside div:</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="newhtml"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="change" value="Insert" onClick="change()"/>
<br/>
<span id="container"></span>
<script>
function change(){
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = document.getElementById("newhtml").value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example to do this with jquery.

```
$('.outputmsg_text').html("YOUR CUSTOM TEXT")
```

Comment: They did not specify that they have jQuery (and a pure JS answer is very simple for something like this)

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mbL2392/)     (REQUIRE JQUERY)

```
<button id="change">Change Text</button>
    <div id="div">
    Some text
    </div>
    <script>
    $("#change").click(function(){
      var name = prompt("What text shoud it be?");
      if(name){
        $("#div").html(name);
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: They did not specify that they have jQuery (and a pure JS answer is very simple for something like this)