# How do I change text within <div> tags with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xss, element

[image: The code]

I need some help on editing elements which are in HTML with JavaScript. Is it possible to change the "text" with javascript? I've tried using `document.getElementById` but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#div_lb .header').textContent = 'bla'`

Comment: Come on, a Google search gives about a zillion results :) Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/how-do-i-replace-text-inside-a-div-element)

Comment: _"I've tried using document.getElementById but I don't think I'm doing it correctly."_ Please show us what you tried.

Comment: @le_m Thank you very much for the fast reply. I tried running this code and it's working! I was wondering if it is possible to display an image instead? Would it be something to do with .src ? Please let me know. Once again, thanks.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#div_lb .header').innerHTML = '<img src="...">'`? Better alternatives include setting a background image / toggling CSS class of that div etc....

Comment: @j08691 Hi. I didn't add it in, because I thought it would be irrelevant le_m has solved this for me anyways.

Comment: It's not irrelevant -- that's probably why you got five downvotes.

Comment: What don't you understand? You need to show what you tried by posting a [mcve] in your question. A picture doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the elemet with a query like you would use in css:

```
var element = document.querySelector('div.header');
```

Change the content using the `textContent` property:

```
element.textContent = "New Content;"
```

Adding image to content:

```
document.querySelector('div.header').innerHTML = "<img src='smiley.gif' alt='Smiley face' height='42' width='42'>";
```

Comment: The image code doesn't work. It just outputs <img src='smiley.gif' alt='Smiley face' height='42' width='42'>. Also may I ask what the 'alt' does?

Comment: @Anonymous try using `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`. The `alt` property is simply text that will be displayed if the image is not available or can not be viewed. It is not required for the image to be displayed.

Comment: <script>element.innerHTML=<img src='image link here';</script> I tried this, didn't work. What mistake did I make?

Comment: @Anonymous The image HTML needs to be assigned like a string in quotations. example: `<script> element.innerHTML="<img src='image link here'>"; </script>`

Comment: Thanks it works now

Answer (score 0):

Simple example with "press me" button that calls a function to change text

```
<html>
<script>
    function changeText(){
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "changed text";
    };
</script>
<body>
    <div id="header">text</div>
    <button onclick="changeText()">press me</button>
</body>
```

```html
<html>
 <script>
  function changeText(){
   document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "changed text";
  };
 </script>
 <body>
  <div id="header">text</div>
  <button onclick="changeText()">press me</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsbyClassName` there are many ways to alter the text.

My answer is that you must think about your structure of the HTML Document.

You can use every ID only once. It is better to use data-lb="detail" etc. and classes for the div´s

Please see this not as an answer only as an tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
<button id="click">
CLICK
</button>
<div class="header" id="textChange">Text</div>
```

And then in your JS -

```
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
$( "#textChange" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
});
```