# Replace text inside HTML leaving other HTML intact with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write pure javascript function to replace the text "Passed" to "Completed". The HTML inside the div#prompt should remain in tact and is variable.  Here is the HTML -

```
<div id="prompt">
  Passed
  <a href="#">Take a survey</a>
  <button type="button" data-behavior="hide.prompt"></button>
</div>
```

I tried replacing text but that doesn't seem to be working

```
var text = document.getElementById('prompt').textContent; 
text.replace("Passed", "Completed");
```

Also tried this -

```
var text = document.getElementById('prompt').innerHTML;
text.replace("Passed", "Completed");
```

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace text inside a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/how-do-i-replace-text-inside-a-div-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace` does not mutate the string, it returns a new one. Strings are immutable.

```
 var text = document.getElementById('prompt');
 text.textContent = text.textContent.replace("Passed", "Completed");
```

---

Actually your element contains a text node that you can override:

```
 document.getElementById('prompt').childNodes[0].textContent = "Completed";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing text, how about toggle a class on the outer `div`.

With that you can also customize its HTML as well.

Stack snippet

```css
.prompt::before {
  content: 'Passed';
}
.prompt.hidden::before {
  content: 'Completed';
}
.prompt.hidden button {
  display: none;
}

/* demo styles */
.prompt button { padding: 5px 20px; }
hr { margin: 20px 0; }
```

```html
<div class="prompt">
  <a href="#">Take a survey</a>
  <button type="button" data-behavior="hide.prompt"></button>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="prompt hidden">  
  <a href="#">Take a survey</a>
  <button type="button" data-behavior="hide.prompt"></button>
</div>
```