# Adding content to HTML <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html

say I have a `<p>` tag like this

```html
<p>some content</p>
```

Is there a way to add more to this, and make it for example

```html
<p>some content on the site</p>
```

Just to clarify I don't want to replace it. I know about both the `innerHTML` method and `.update()` but these replace the text not add to it.

Comment: Have you tried googling first? Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/how-do-i-replace-text-inside-a-div-element/121824

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace text inside a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/how-do-i-replace-text-inside-a-div-element)

Comment: @Alex I saw that, but I want to add to the text, not replace it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply fetch the innerText and update with new value:

```js
document.getElementById("myContent").innerText = document.getElementById("myContent").innerText + " is now changed";
```

```html
<p id="myContent">some content</p>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

it must be somehow you can find that `<p>`, based on how your document is:

- Using the "id" attribute
- Using getElementBy... (tagName, class)...

If the

content is simply a text, just use `textContent`
If it is more complicated, consider using `innerHTML` instead.