# How can I replace specific characters in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the comma into an apostrophe in this div.

```
<div id="range" class="range-slider">   
  <div class="something">15,000.00</div>
</div>
```

So instead of 15,000.00 I would like to do 15'000.00

I cannot alter the HTML so I think I need to achieve this in JS, right?

Do I need to use the `changeText` function?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) | [How do I replace text inside a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/how-do-i-replace-text-inside-a-div-element/18723036)

Answer (score 3):

There is no native `changeText` function in JavaScript. You can change the text content of an element using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property and use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace `,` to `'`.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector(".something")

elem.textContent = elem.textContent.replace(",", "'");
```

```html
<div id="range" class="range-slider">   
  <div class="something">15,000.00</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I get an error

Uncaught TypeError: elem is null

Comment: @Tycin what query did you use inside the `querySelector`? You need to put a `.` before the class name.

Comment: Yep, this is what I used. In my case

<script type="text/javascript">
        let elem = document.querySelector(".noUi-tooltip")

elem.textContent = elem.textContent.replace(",", "'");
    </script>

Comment: @Tycin make sure you load the JavaScript after loading the body i.e put JavaScript after closing body tag. Also make sure, element with class `noUi-tooltip` exists.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [TechySharnav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70849942/12792257)'s answer, you can also query for the classname directly.

```
var el = documents.getElementByClassNames("something");
el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(',',"'");
```

Comment: This will only work if OP wants to replace the text in the **first** occurring element that matches the `.something` selector.